# How do I dynamically change the size of UI controls in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview

I've got an iOS app which is essentially a glorified web browser locked to the client's mobile website. It was originally designed -- and the storyboard properties for the UIWebView hard coded -- for the iPhone 4S; on an iPhone 5/5S, 6, and 6 Plus the UIWebView won't take up the whole screen.

How do I fix this? Here are screenshots of the app on an iPhone 5S and 6 Plus (URL changed to Bing.com since the boundary of the edge of the UIWebView is more obvious):

[screenshot on iPhone 5S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgQUD.png)
[screenshot of iPhone 6 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqJyB.jpg)

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the following options

**option 1:**  If your webView Created programatically

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

**Option 2:** connect webView with IBOutlet

in **ViewDidLoad** method

```
 yourWebView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: While my scenario was using Xamarin, the concept is the same; here's what ended up working in the ViewDidLoad() method in C#:

webView.Frame = this.View.Frame;